# Node.js, angular.js with mobile app and AI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, web-applications

I'm a novice in programming. I know a little about programming. Previously I have worked on some projects for my College with Java, PHP and C++. I'm not good at any of those.

I have a tremendous enthusiasm for the web. Also in AI and web-based Mobile application. I have practiced a little of HTML/CSS, JS, PHP, CMS's with no discipline.

Please help me out where I can start, step by step process to mastering my dream.

Thanks in advance.

I shall look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). **Research, try something, add your code & point your problem**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends upon your choice of action, you would basically have two options UI/UX and Core language developer. As i am a full stack developer working in Mobile, i will explain how i started.

UI/UX
Start practicing with HTML5 and CSS3 since its most advanced and accepted.
I would prefer:
https://www.w3schools.com/html 
Next Learn CSS3 and Bootstrap
Bootstrap website itself provides a good documentation for it. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started

Next Task for you would be Javascript which is everything if you ask me.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/

You can Learn Angularjs if you want, as its really important. but i would ask you to leap to Angular2 and Typescript which follows the OOPS concept.

Youtube also provides great tutorials especially thenewboston channel

Since you have interest in AI, start with some python, then move on to R Programming.

I hope this would help you.

Answer (score 1):

1. learn JavaScript core consecpt [W3school JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/)
2. Angularjs from [Angularjs](http://angular.io/docs)
3. Nodejs from [tutorialspoint -nodejs](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/)

try to create small web app

Comment: Thank you V5NXT and Rahul Prajapati for your precious time. I will definitely follow your advice.